# How to remove flex layout

Tags: angular, uninstallation, angular-flex-layout

I have a folder path in the source code, which is in visual studio web spectrum project. How can I proceed  remove flex layout in the code. Do I need to run a simple command in the terminal or edit code?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove completely flex layout form your project you need to do these:
1- Uninstall flex layout. Run this command;

```
npm uninstall flex-layout
```

When you run this command you'll see in your package.json that flex layout dependency was removed.

2- In your app.module.ts file or any module file that you are using for flex layout, remove the import.

That's all for me.
Let me know if you fix it.

Comment: `npm uninstall @angular/flex-layout` use this command to uninstall flex-layout. I tried using the above command and it didn't work. Rest do everything as said in the answer.